# Tengo un problema con el intent al abrir otra activity

Tags: android, android-intent

Buenas noches amigos puej la verdad no se que esta mal me estoy ahogando en un problemilla chico pues le cuento que un intent para abrir otra activity no me funciona no se que esta mal pero los otros intents si: aqui el codigo:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnAgregarSoporte){
        Intent abrirAgregarSoporteActivity = new Intent(this,AgregarSoporteActivity.class);
        startActivity(abrirAgregarSoporteActivity);
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnPublicarAnuncio){
        Intent abrirAgregarUbicacionYProdInm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AgregarUbicacionYproductoInmueble.class);
        startActivity(abrirAgregarUbicacionYProdInm);
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnVerAnuncios){
            Intent AbrirAnuncios = new Intent(this,AnunciosActivity.class);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pero llega",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // inclusive llega hasta aqui cuando quito la linea de abajo
        startActivity(AbrirAnuncios); // cuando quito esta linea funciona pero obviamente no abre la otra activity si no que muestra el mensaje de la anterior linea
    }




}
```

pues como ven todos los intents de aqui funcionan excepto el que marco con comentario la verdad no se q pasa me he fijado todo y nada pueden ayudarme porfa, pues se cierra la aplicacion al presionar ese boton ver anuncios . gracias.

por si necesitan algo mas , puedo modificar la pregunta y añadir mas codigo o lo que necesiten porfa.

Comment: Ya lo resolvi muchas gracias :).

Answer (score 0):

Es incorrecto usar `this` como contexto dentro del método :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
 ...
 ...
 ...
}
```

Debes usar como contexto la llamada a el método `getApplicationContext()` :

```
Intent AbrirAnuncios = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnunciosActivity.class);
```

O también hacer referencia a la Activity, suponiendo que tu Activity se llama `MainActivity` :

```
Intent AbrirAnuncios = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AnunciosActivity.class);
```

---

En ocasiones agregamos Activity a nuestros proyectos pero estas no se registran automáticamente en el `AndroidManifest.xml`, agrega la actividad dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` para que quede registrada en tu aplicacion.

```
 <application
     ...
      ...
      <activity android:name=".AnunciosActivity"/>
  </application>
```

Comment: pero igual me funciona con el this amigo, cual seria la diferencia?

Comment: La differencia sería que no existe la clase activity o comunmente no registraste en AndroidManifest.xml la activity.

Answer (score 0):

Como dice el comentario anterior es incorrecto utilizar `this` dentro de el método `onclick`, así que la solución seria:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnAgregarSoporte){
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AgregarSoporteActivity.class));
    }
    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnPublicarAnuncio){
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AgregarUbicacionYproductoInmueble.class));
    }

    if(v.getId() == R.id.btnVerAnuncios){
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AnunciosActivity.class));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Pero llega",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  // inclusive llega hasta aqui cuando quito la linea de abajo
// cuando quito esta linea funciona pero obviamente no abre la otra activity si no que muestra el mensaje de la anterior linea
        }
    }
```

Elimine varias lineas que tenias y lo simplifique a una sola, espero te funcione. Suerte y saludos.

Comment: pero igual me funciona con el this amigo, cual seria la diferencia?

Comment: Hola que tal en algunas partes el this no funciona, ya que el this no solo hace referencia a la clase sino que tambien al contexto y en muchos casos a los view, asi que en algunos metodos no funciona.